# How to color cells based on being column maximum in Bokeh Datatable?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, bokeh

I'm making a datatable in bokeh.models, and trying to have each column max value highlighted a light green or blue. I see solutions to conditionally highlight cells using HTMLTemplateFormatter.

E.g.

```
    dict1 = {'x':[0]*6,'y':[0,1,0,1,0,1]}
    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict1)
    
    template="""
    <div style="background:<%= 
        (function colorfromint(){
            if(value == 1){
                return("blue")}
            else{return("red")}
            }()) %>; 
        color: white"> 
    <%= value %></div>
    """

formater =  HTMLTemplateFormatter(template=template)
columns = [
    TableColumn(field="x", title="x"),
    TableColumn(field="y", title="y",formatter=formater)
]

data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=800)

show(data_table)
```

Is there a way to change the template code to conditionally highlight the maximum in every column?